# Can't Find iPhone Simulator's SQLite Database : Using Magical Record

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, magicalrecord

**In my application's documents folder, I do not find my SQLite database**

> Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/"random app
>   id"/Documents/

^This folder is empty

MagicalRecord seems to be working,  I just have no idea how to find the database.

I use the following to set up Magical Record

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
```

**So where does MagicalRecord store its database?**

Comment: You can follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133022/ios-8-store-sqlite-file-location-core-data/27461267#27461267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MagicalRecord stores, by default, all data stores in the following location:

{App Folder}/Library/Application Support/{App Name from Info.plist}/{storeName.sqlite}

This is easily accessible from the simulator as well as documents.

Comment: I only have three files in this location instead of sqlite; AppName  AppName-shm AppName-wal

Comment: @GangstaGraham The wal file is the SQLite write ahead log, and the shm is the SQLite shared memory file. The "AppName" file is most likely your SQLite database.

Comment: I figured out that in the Store Named string I inputted "AppName" instead of "AppName.sqlite", I just thought it would add in the sqlite by itself, anyways thank you SO SO much, the database really helps in understanding what the program is doing, so it's great to be able to access it again. Thanks a lot! @rickerbh

Comment: Any reason of why you put in /Application Support/ instead /Caches/ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can log your SQlite file location using the following NSPersistentStore MR addition :

```
[NSPersistentStore MR_urlForStoreName:[MagicalRecord defaultStoreName]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the sqlite file then just do a search in OSX for that file to find the directory. Otherwise the file was never created.

Make sure you are setting up the CoreData stack correctly as per the [documents](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).

```
+ (void) setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;
```

Comment: Do you know if Core Data needs a database file, or if that's optional? Because Core Data (through the Magical Record wrapper) is working.

Comment: CoreData can use sqlite as its persistent store but no, it does not require sqlite. It needs to be configured for whatever store type you choose.

Comment: Check here. It goes over setting up the CoreData stack (sqlite filename) https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: I did this and it still is not in the documents folder, searching for it, let's hope I find it

Comment: Nope, @MarkM I searched for AppName.sqlite in Finder, and got no results. :(

Comment: Check out this tutorial. Maybe it can help. http://maniacdev.com/2012/04/tutorial-the-basics-of-using-the-magical-record-core-data-library

Answer (score 0):

Swift + Xcode 7 + simulator 9.0

Please go to your AppDelegate.swift

change

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed("yourDBName.sqlite")
```

to

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed("yourDBName.sqlite")
```

Now you can locate the yourDBName.sqlite at 
/Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"random app id"/data/Containers/Data/Application/"random app id"/Library/Application Support/ProjectName

There is a useful tool: simPHolders2 (http://simpholders.com)
simPHolders easy to access all application folders