# Where sqlite database iphone simulator is created

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin

Hello I am making an app that creates a database, is recording and listing smoothly.
However, I need to check how they are being recorded data in the database using sql query
But I find the place where it was created the base.
I am using the iPhone Simulator 5s iOS 9.3.
I searched the folder (~ / Library / Application Support / iPhone Simulator /), and there I found.
I'm looking in the right place?
Thank you

Comment: Have your app log the path to the database file. Then it will be easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the location was before XCode 6. Now the location is  (~ / Library / Developer / Core Simulator / Devices /)

For a detailed description, refer this link,

[Sqlite File Location Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133022/ios-8-store-sqlite-file-location-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

I found 7.1 and 8.4 version this
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Click by file right - "Show Package Content"
Content/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `sqlite` file then log it's path and then you just copy that path after that open Finder -> Press Command+Shift+g -> Paste path and press return. You will directly moved to thar file.