# Where is the Core Data file located?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I use Core Data in my application, and I want to know that where is the SQLite file located.

I have already read the relative post and I didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

During initialization of the Core Data Stack you decide, where the database file will be located. The standard place is the documents directory. See Apple Developer - [Initializing the Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1).

You will find there the following code

```
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
/* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory. 
*/
let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
```

The `storeURL` is the file URL you are looking for (and `docURL` is just a directory without a file name included).

You can also find this directory using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last! as String
```

Check [IOS 8 Store sqlite File Location Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133022/ios-8-store-sqlite-file-location-core-data) for other ideas like `find` used in Terminal for example.