# Path to Core Data database with Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

When i use to work with core data i often use that code to show me path to .sqlite database:

```
NSLog(@"%@ path-core",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

However, when i add Magical Record to my project, i used this instead:

```
NSLog(@"magical record path to SQLite base %@", [NSPersistentStore MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl]);
```

Which print path:

```
/Users/Necrosoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68A05D98-7949-4F90-BFB9-9C8A368F411B/data/Containers/Data/Application/7EC45D6A-B20E-4EC2-B657-1425F714518F/Library/Application%20Support/MyApp/CoreDataStore.sqlite
```

But i cant find CoreDataStore.sqlite. When i try "go to" with finder, i simply find an empty folder. But i guess there is actually .sqlite db stored in here. So how can i access it?

UPDATE:
In Application Support folder there is actual 4 items, but i see only 3, 1 missing (hiding) is the one i need. How to get it?

[image]

Comment: this may help you but it is in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434354/nslogging-println-sqlite-db-file-location-in-swift/40325883#40325883

Comment: Look how is constructed `MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl` in the code: with `MR_directory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory` not `NSDocumentDirectory`, which can be seen in the path `/Library/Application%20Support`. Just follow that logic. It appends also the app name `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];`. Source: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSPersistentStore%2BMagicalRecord.m

Comment: @Larme so how can i access this file?..

Comment: `NSString *path = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey]];`?

Comment: @Larme what is kCFBundleNameKey?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/kcfbundlenamekey
And from the previous code, just add `CoreDataStore.sqlite` at the end I guess. Oh, I misread your question, do like Ashok said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722844/core-data-files-location-ios-10/40103564#40103564

Comment: @Larme for some reason .db stored in Application Support folder is an empty and has different name. I guess it may be something related to Magical Record inner usage.

Comment: Can't Find iPhone Simulator's SQLite Database : Using Magical Record http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426536/cant-find-iphone-simulators-sqlite-database-using-magical-record

Comment: i feel you have to look in to this https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/91

Answer (score 2):

*The ultimate goal for you is finding `CoreDataStore.sqlite` file.*

*open your terminal and type `find ~ -name 'CoreDataStore.sqlite'` and hit enter.*

```
Ashoks-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Ashok$ find ~ -name 'CoreDataStore.sqlite'
/Users/Ashok/Desktop/CoreDataStore.sqlite
```

*From above output you can clearly see the path of your sqlite db*

*I hope it helps:-)*

Comment: thanks, but terminal just stuck for about 30 secs, then return nothing..

Comment: check Core Data file's Location iOS 10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722844/core-data-files-location-ios-10/40103564#40103564

Comment: make sure your project is running

Comment: run this command to see all the hidden folder `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.` and then Hold the 'Option/alt' key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Comment: latest version.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426536/cant-find-iphone-simulators-sqlite-database-using-magical-record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132514/discussion-between-ashok-and-evgeniy-kleban).